# How do you transform a CompletableFuture of one type to another?

Tags: java, completable-future

I currently convert my `CompletableFuture<X>` to `CompletableFuture<Void>` as shown below but I was wondering if there was a better way.

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Void> packetEncrypted(ByteBuffer engineToSocketData) {
    return realChannel.write(engineToSocketData).thenApply(c -> empty());
}

public Void empty() {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're effectively trying to transform the completed value of your `CompletableFuture` into a value of type `Void`. Presumably you want to propagate any exception if that future was completed exceptionally.

`CompletableFuture` provides [`thenApply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenApply-java.util.function.Function-) for this basic transformation, but other methods can also be used.

In your case, you'll want to ignore the value from the source future and return `null`, since `null` is the only possible value for the type `Void`. However, there needs to be some hint for the compiler that you're targeting the type `Void`.

Either be explicit by providing an explicit type argument to the invocation of `thenApply`

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> packetEncrypted(ByteBuffer engineToSocketData) {
    return realChannel.write(engineToSocketData).<Void> thenApply(c -> null);
}
```

or be explicit by casting to the appropriate type in the lambda expression

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> packetEncrypted(ByteBuffer engineToSocketData) {
    return realChannel.write(engineToSocketData).thenApply(c -> (Void) null);
}
```

Your solution achieves the same result, since the value is known to be of the correct type, but it involves an extra method invocation

```
@Override
public CompletableFuture<Void> packetEncrypted(ByteBuffer engineToSocketData) {
    return realChannel.write(engineToSocketData).thenApply(c -> empty());
}
```

All of these solutions will propagate the exception, if any, of the origial `CompletableFuture`.

Thank you to [Luis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152203/how-do-you-transform-a-completablefuture-of-one-type-to-another/37152555?noredirect=1#comment96109135_37152555), you could also just use `thenAccept` with a `Consumer` doing nothing:

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> packetEncrypted(ByteBuffer engineToSocketData) {
    return realChannel.write(engineToSocketData).thenAccept(c -> {}):
}
```

---

The behavior is the same for any other type. `thenApply` lets you perform any `Function` on the result of a `CompletableFuture`.

For example, I can have a future that's meant to complete with `String` that's meant to be converted to an `Integer`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> futureLine = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> "1234");
    CompletableFuture<Integer> theNumber = futureLine.thenApply(Integer::parseInt);
    System.out.println(theNumber.get());
}
```

`thenApply` receives the completed value and transforms it by passing it to an invocation of `Integer#parseInt(String)`. Since `parseInt` has a return type of `int`, the return type of `thenApply` is inferred to `CompletableFuture<Integer>`.